# How to resize icons without losing quality?

Tags: gimp, icon, png, resize

I have icons (in png format) with a resolution of  about 500x500 pixels and want to use them in app development around size 30x30 pixels. But when I resize them, they become very aliased.

**How can I resize them so they remain crisp, without aliasing or blur?** I am using Windows 10. I have GIMP installed, and am happy to use any free software.

For example I have a heart icon[image: Original Image]

When I scale it down in the app (by setting the width and height programatically), it becomes aliased:
[image: Scaled Image]

Comment: not decrease, resize is the proper term. Decrease would be more specific to file size. But most likely for such a drastic resizing you'd have to redo them or you'll lose too much detail.

Comment: On the other hand, what file format are these icons? What tools do you have available? Please [edit] your question to add more detail.

Comment: I can't help but think that `.svg` would be a better file format. — There are some asset managers that can export files in different formats, colors and sizes. On Mac I use [iconJar](https://geticonjar.com/). That said, I get that this is probably not useful information for you in this case, but maybe in the future...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using bitmap files like PNG, it is always better to have a specialised program handle sizing. Though browsers have been much improved in this regard throughout the years, they are not as heavily optimised as specialised image handling programs such as Photoshop or GIMP.

**Photoshop** has a batch image resizer, which you can find under *File > Scripts > Image processor*.

**GIMP** does not have a handy out-of-the-box tool, but has some options. If you're not afraid of scripting, you can use the [Command Line Interface](https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/). There are also a few plugins that provide a Use Interface, such as [BIMP](https://alessandrofrancesconi.it/projects/bimp/) or [David's Batch Processor](http://members.ozemail.com.au/~hodsond/dbp.html).

**ImageMagick** is a command line tool that can handle all kinds of image manipulation, including batch resizing. You can find a tutorial [here](https://dototot.com/imagemagick-tutorial-batch-resize-images-command-line/).

Comment: I used ImageMagick. It made it a bit too blurry but I figured that scaling the image down partially and then programitically resizing found a nice middle ground. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it helped.